# Images all added to last sprite, but it is already in a loop

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

What I am trying to do is:

1.) I parse vectors into the class. It contains simple text,

2.) In a loop it adds the text and (load then add 1 image) into a sprite.

3.) It loops, and then creates a list of boxes where each box has some text and 1 image.

The problem:

I am having a problem. The text adds into the sprite with no problem. It adds all the textfields to it, but all the images are added to the last sprite.

Thanks for your time!

My Code:

```
for (var k:int = 0; k < test.length; k++) 
            {
                var Bolder:Listing8 = new Listing8();

                Bolder.x=20;





                if(test[k].pic1){
                        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
   var loading111:loading1 = new loading1;
   Bolder.addChild(loading111);
                    loader.load(new 

            URLRequest("http://www.rentaid.info/rent/"+test[k].pic1));
                    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,  onImageLoaded);


        Bolder.addChild(loader);    

                    }





            function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {
removeChild(loading111);    


                        e.currentTarget.loader.content.height =50;


e.target.content.x = 130;
                e.target.content.y = 15;
                e.target.content.height = 70;
                e.target.content.width = 140;






                var bf:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf1:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf2:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf3:TextField = new TextField();



                bf3.width = 100;
                bf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

                bf.width = 100;
                bf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf1.width = 100;
                bf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.width = 100;
                bf1.y= bf.height+5;



                    // Pulling the textfields content out from the current bookVO

                bf.text = test[k].nobed;
                bf1.text = test[k].zip;
                bf2.text = test[k].Location;
                bf3.text = test[k].price;

                bf.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.2
                Bolder.addChild(bf);
                Bolder.addChild(bf1);
                Bolder.addChild(bf2);
                Bolder.addChild(bf3);






                    // position the object based on the accumulating variable.
                Bolder.y = currentY;



                Bolder.mouseChildren = false;    // ignore children mouseEvents
                Bolder.mouseEnabled = true;      // enable mouse on the object - normally set to true by default
                Bolder.useHandCursor = true;     // add hand cursor on mouse over
                Bolder.buttonMode = true; 
                trace ('add image with index', k);
                image[k]= new Sprite();
                image[k].addChild(Bolder);
                image.mouseChildren = true;    // ignore children mouseEvents
                image.mouseEnabled = true;      // enable mouse on the object - normally set to true by default
                image.useHandCursor = true;     // add hand cursor on mouse over
                image.buttonMode = true; 
                image[k].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscene);

                currentY += Bolder.height + 10;

            }








            if( test.length > 0 )
             {
                _contentHolder = new Sprite();


                addChild(_contentHolder);






       for (var j:int = 0; j < test.length; j++) {



                _contentHolder.addChild(image[j]);



    }
```

Comment: is it because of the Event.COMPLETE? So the images load are added after its completed, so the text adds before it? But then not sure why they are added to the last sprite.

Comment: Just ask one question at a time and you'll get the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904606/how-to-load-all-images-first-before-adding-to-stage/23904863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend you to put function declaration into a function.
This is the reason of your confusion.

Your program at first executes all code(for example 10 times) **EXCEPT** this part:

```
function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {
    e.currentTarget.loader.content.height =50;
    var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite;
    sprite.y += sprite.height + 10;
    sprite.addChild(e.target.content as Bitmap);
    Bolder.addChild(sprite);
}
```

And then executes this part 10 times. And in this situation Bolder is always  Bolder == “your_10th_Bolder”

This how events work.

Adding loader as child may help:

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.rentaid.info/rent/"+test[k].pic1));
Bolder.addChild(loader);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,  onImageLoaded);
```

and in handler doing this:

```
function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {
    e.target.content.x = 123;
    e.target.content.y = 456;
    e.target.content.height = 789;
    e.target.content.width = 123;
}
```

Comment: Hi!! It works but can i ask just a little more? I am trying to add an image(a loading sign), in the box(Bolder) and remove it when the image is loaded, i tried adding it but when i removeChild i don't know how to get the right parent, and i kept getting an error The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller. I added the edit above.

Comment: You should create new question, because my answer is too large to put it in comment, and I allowed only one answer per question on stackowerflow. Meanwhile I will save my answer on my computer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908416/removing-parent-addchild-added-in-loop I created it here